# Hide div when input is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to hide a div when an input element is empty (the user has not typed anything in). I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785622/what-jquery-do-i-need-to-hide-a-div-class-if-an-input-value-is-empty) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858761/show-hide-div-when-input-field-is-emptyjquery-javascript) but they do not work for me. the div I want to hide has an id of `search-result-container` and the input has an id of `search-input`. **I need to hide the div when the input is empty.**

Here is the relevant part of my HTML code:

```
 <!-- Html Elements for Search -->
<div id="search-container">
  <input type="text" name="search-input" id="search-input" placeholder="&#128270; type to search...">

  <h1></h1>
  <h1></h1>
  <h1></h1>
</div>
</div>

<h1></h1>
<h1></h1>
<h1></h1>
<h1></h1>

<div class="container" id="search-result-container" class="show_hide">

  <ul id="results-container"></ul>

  <!-- Script pointing to search-script.js -->
  <script src=[SEARCH JS]></script>

  <!-- Configuration -->


  <script>
    SimpleJekyllSearch({
      searchInput: document.getElementById('search-input'),
      resultsContainer: document.getElementById('results-container'),
      searchResultTemplate: '<a href="{url}"><h1>{title}</h1></a><h2 class="searchresults">{date}</span></h2>',
      json: [JSON URL]
    })
  </script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




</div>
</div>
```

Any help will be very much appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: you should probably be loading in the JQuery script before any script in which you use JQuery (if you use it in search-script.js)

Comment: Gerado BLANCO See my edit (in bold)

Comment: Please show in your question the logic you tried to use to solve your problem that is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple way of doing what you want using jquery:

```js
$('#search-input').on('input', function() {
  $('#search-result-container').css('display', $(this).val()  !== '' ? 'block' : 'none')
});
```

```css
#search-result-container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id ="search-input">
<div id="search-result-container">This will be hidden</div>
```

Comment: Will this interfere with my other JS which contains the search-script.js?

Comment: By reading [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)

Comment: [Working](https://jsfiddle.net/ejv0e6pg/2/) Did you read the link I sent? you need to include it before the script.

Answer (score 0):

Based on both links you post:
HTML:

```
<input id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Write here"/>

<div id="search-result-container" class="hide">
  <p>
    Results...
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

JS:

```
$('#search-input')
    .on('keyup', function(e) {
    var input = $(this).val();
    input.length ?
            $('#search-result-container').show() :
      $('#search-result-container').hide();
  })
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sL5ue12p/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use This Way:

```
<script>
    // Your div id which you wants to hide
    var hide = document.getElementById("yourDivId"); 
   
    //Your input field id
    var textarea = document.getElementById("YourInputFieldId");

    //Simple Logic
    if (textarea.value == "") {
        hide.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```